# Kali Linux: Airodump does not find any stations (possible incompatible software)

Tags: kali-linux

I recently installed kali (64 bit for bootable usb) on my new computer and I am running in an issue where nor airodump, nor wifite detect any networks nearby. My wireless cart is a Quacom Atheros (QCA61x4) so it should be supported. Wifite worked fine on my last laptop and managed to find all networks fairly quickly. On the new one, however, even after a 2 minute scan, no stations are found. When running airodump-ng wlan0mon the window opens and it starts searching through the channels however nothing is listed in the table. I can connect via WiFi and through the panel for connecting to internet all networks are listed. There are no visible error messages, simply because there are no errors.

I doubt that it is incompatible hardware as Atheros cards are supported.

```
rfkill list
2: wlan0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do an injection test like "aireplay-ng 9". even though atheros is supported you might also need to update the firmware for it for example ath10k

Comment: It gives output: Opening 9
open failed: No such file or directory
Read 0 packets.

No networks found, exiting.


Quitting aircrack-ng...